# Как сделать так чтобы objectMapper конвертировал объекты с final полями?

Tags: java, json, jackson, final

Как сделать так чтобы objectMapper конвертировал объекты с final полями?
У меня есть класс Answer:

```
public class Answer {
    private final String text;

    public Answer(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Answer) {
            String s = ((Answer) obj).getText();
            return this.text.equals(s);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

И класс Reading:

```
public class Reading {

    private Answer trueAnswer;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Reading{" +
                "text=" + trueAnswer +
                '}';
    }

    public Answer getTrueAnswer() {
        return trueAnswer;
    }

    public void setTrueAnswer(Answer trueAnswer) {
        this.trueAnswer = trueAnswer;
    }

    public Reading() {
    }

    public Reading(Answer text) {
        this.trueAnswer = text;
    }
}
```

А также json файл

```json
{
  "trueAnswer": {
    "text": "Answer1|1"
  }
}
```

И класс Main для их реализации

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
          
            Reading reading = mapper.readValue(Paths.get("src/main/resources/read.json").toFile(), Reading.class);
            System.out.println(reading);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Я хочу чтобы мой ObjectMapper сконвертировал содержимое json файла, но это не получается сделать так как в классе Answer нету пустого конструктора и я не могу его создать так как поля объявлены как final

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вопрос, в нём слишком мало информации, чтобы понять, в чём ваша проблема. Ещё было бы хорошо, если бы вы его немного лучше оформили.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте так:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Answer {

    private final String text;

    @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)
    public Answer(@JsonProperty("text") String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Answer) {
            String s = ((Answer) obj).getText();
            return this.text.equals(s);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо все работает)
Можете подсказать, где я смогу подробно изучить это тему?

Comment: @TBK добрый день! под темой вы имеете в виду Jackson? если да, то в целом в инете довольно много ресурсов и, что касается обучения, как по мне, это вопрос субъективный (кому-то лучше читать книги, кому-то смотреть видео, а кому-то еще что-то). посему дать вам рекомендации по поводу учебного материала, который подходит конкретно вам, достаточно сложно. могу лишь привести пример ресурса,где информация относительно актуальна и содержит практические примеры с описанием (как по мне, это довольно неплохо): https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-immutable-objects

Comment: Да я имела ввиду  Jackson, а также сам objectMapper и  @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES) данную аннотацию
Спасибо большое за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Два варианта

### Десериализация с помощью конструктора

```
@JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)
public Answer(@JsonProperty("text") String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
```

### Десериализация с помощью Builder-а

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Answer.Builder.class)
public class Answer {
  // тут все как и раньше
    
  @JsonPOJOBuilder
  static class Builder {
    String text;
    
    Builder withText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        return this;
    }
    
    public Answer build() {
        return new Answer(text);
    } 
  }
}
```